# Browserify: Nested/Conditional Requires

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs, browserify

In the CommonJS/Browserify module below, how can I avoid importing both `foo` and `bar` every time -- instead importing only the one that is needed based on the conditional in `init()`?

```
var Foo = require('foo'),
    Bar = require('bar'),

Component = function(config) {
  this.type = config.type;
  this.init();
};

Component.prototype = {

  init: function() {
    var instance = null;

    switch (this.type) {
      case ('foo'):
        instance = new Foo(...);
        break;
      case ('bar'):
        instance = new Bar(...);
        break;
    }
  }
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Component = function(config) {
  this.type = config.type;
  this.init();
};

Component.prototype = {

  init: function() {
    var instance = null;

    switch (this.type) {
      case ('foo'):
        instance = new (require('foo'))(...);
        break;
      case ('bar'):
        instance = new (require('bar'))(...);
        break;
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Does this actually avoid importing both files though? I'm pretty sure that when Browserify inlines the `require()` statements it will bundle up everything, regardless of whether it's in a conditional, but I may be wrong.

Comment: of course it will bundle up everything, there is no way to know the result at compile time

Comment: You might bee looking for https://github.com/niksy/browserify-require-async

Answer (score 13):

If you came here (like me) because there is some modules **you want to exclude from the bundle** depending on a condition in your code, for example :

```
// I want browserify to ignore `nodeOnlyModule` because it
// can't be browserified (for example if it uses native extensions, etc ...)
var isBrowser = typeof window === 'undefined'
if (!isBrowser) var nodeOnlyModule = require('nodeOnlyModule')
```

There is different options (see [the docs](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify)) :

- browserify's `ignore` option will simply replace the module you don't want to bundle by an empty stub, and bundle that instead
- `exclude` will exclude the module altogether, your code will then throw a "not found" error if you try to import it.
- you can use the `browser` field from your `package.json` file. With this you can provide a mapping of files to import, in effect overriding node's module resolve algorithm when browserifying.